# How to Disable Full Row Select in WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have some questions about the selection using WPF ListView:

- How to disable full row select in WPF ListView (with GridView) like Windows Forms ListView?
- For example, selecting only the first column, or selecting until the last column?
- Also, do not select when i click on the empty space right from the last column?

I'm using VS 2015 and .NET 4.0.

Any suggestions in XAML or C# code behind would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need `ListView` for this task? [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx) sounds like a right tool for the job. You can set [SelectionUnit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionunit(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Cell` and [SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Extended`, which fits the scenario you described. And it does not handle clicking on the empty space after the last column (also you can set last column with `Width="*"` to remove this space completely).